# Opencart Mega Filter (не работает javascript после фильтрации)

Tags: javascript, opencart

Mega Filter (не работает javascript после фильтрации), если обновить страницу javascript начинает работать с примененным фильтром.

Находил несколько тем с данной проблемой, но решения так и не нашел.

Много решал задач, но это прям вопрос года! )

Вопрос: куда нужно вставлять javascript, чтобы после фильтрации работал javascript.

Спасибо, очень буду рад решению этой проблемы :))

OcStore 2.3.0.2.3

Comment: У Вас тема не стандартная? Есть ли ссылка на сайт?

Comment: Ссылку бы на сайт, так сложно сказать. А по моей практики с mega filter часто проблемы.